# Using RVM from within a service context

Tags: bash, services, rvm

I have a user set up on Ubuntu 14.

If I check when logged in as the user

```
build@linux-build-agent-1:~$ type rvm | head -1
rvm is a function
```

However, this machine is going to be a teamcity agent...

When a job is run in the context of the teamcity service we see

```
[13:19:11][Step 1/1] RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
[13:19:11][Step 1/1] 
[13:19:11][Step 1/1] You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
[13:19:11][Step 1/1] Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
[13:19:11][Step 1/1] Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.
```

I've tried several commands trying to force the service to run in a login shell

```
su - build -c 'source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" && /home/build/buildAgent/bin/agent.sh start'


sudo -u build -i bash -lc '/home/build/buildAgent/bin/agent.sh start'
su - build -c '/home/build/buildAgent/bin/agent.sh start'
```

within the `/etc/init.d/` script with no effect.

If I run `source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` at the head of the script in teamcity then everything is OK but there are multiple users and I can't ask them all to remember to do that.

Is this how I've installed RVM or..?

---

To clarify:

1) when I'm logged in as the user over SSH rvm is installed correctly and functions as expected. As shown by `type rvm | head -1` => 'rvm is a function'
2) when a service logs in as the user rvm is not working correctly.

I want rvm to work when running in the context of the service so that users don't have to explicitly `source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` in their build scripts

Typically this issue is caused by not running as a login shell. So I need to know either how to run a service as a login shell. Or how to fangle rvm so that it can work outside of the login shell context

Comment: Where is the rvm function defined?

Comment: `which rvm` gives `/home/build/.rvm/bin/rvm` I think it was already installed on the VM but my installation script reinstalls it anyway. Using instructions here https://rvm.io/

Comment: Well, your `type` output shows it is a function, so it must be defined in a file you're sourcing somewhere. Presumably one of the `profile` files like `~/.profile` or `/etc/profile`. What problem are you trying to solve here? The `RVM is not a function. . .` or the login shell issue? Are they the same problem? Two separate ones? What needs to be run in a login shell? The `agent.sh` script?

Comment: @terdon does that clarification help?

Comment: Yes, thanks. The difference between login and non-login shells is basically just what files are sourced when the shell is started. I am guessing you could solve this by defining `rvm` function in one of the file sourced by non-login shells instead of where you currently have it. So, where is the rvm function defined at the moment? Is it in `~/.profile`? `/etc/profile`? `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: It was in .bash_profile and .bashrc (which I thought should have made it work). I've just uninstalled it completely using the wonderful `rvm implode` so I can retrace my steps and see what the what

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54568/discussion-between-terdon-and-paul-dambra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `su - build -c foo.sh`, you are starting a login shell, which then launches `foo.sh`. The script `foo.sh`, however, is running in its own subshell (that's how scripts work) and the type of that shell depends on the [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) of the script. So, `su - -c foo.sh` is not making `foo.sh` run in a login shell, it is just running a login shell which then launches `foo.sh`.

So, edit `/home/build/buildAgent/bin/agent.sh` and change this:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

to this:

```
#!/bin/sh -l
```

That will make it run in a login shell and should cause it to read the `/etc/profile`, and `~/.profile` files and bring in your function. Please note that `~/.bash_profile` is not relevant here. This is a file that is only read by `bash`, and not `sh` which, on Ubuntu, is actually `dash`.

Comment: hmmm, I had to change it to /bin/bash -l before it picked it up in the agent.sh script. Which if I add the head foo call to it now prints out 'rvm is a function' frustratingly teamcity run scripts now report rvm is /home/build/.rvm/bin/rvm which this https://rvm.io/workflow/scripting says means that in the context of the teamcity script it is a binary...

Comment: @PaulD'Ambra that's odd since `dash` is supposed to have an `-l` option. Could it be that you were using `~/.bash_profile` instead of `~/.profile`?

Comment: hmmm, I can add a shebang to the teamcity scripts and if I add -l to that it works...